# TYPO3 Ext. tx_news and absolute links for RSS View

Tags: typo3, tx-news

i use the *tx_news* Extension and i need a absolute url to a single news.
The `<n:link [...] />` build a correct link to an single news, but it's not a absolute link.

This don't working:

```
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}"  uriOnly="1" absloute="1" />
```

And with `<f:uri.page absolute="1" />` i can't link to a single newsitem.

But i don't find any other way to build me a absolute link to a single news.
Maybe have someone a little resolution for this problem?

I need this for the RSS-Page for link to newsitems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in [**reference document**](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Templating/ViewHelpers/LinkViewHelper.html) this viewhelper gets optional `configuration` param which allows to pass an array of [`typolink`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink/Index.html) settings.

```
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" uriOnly="1" configuration="{forceAbsoluteUrl:1}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the additional configuration parameter of the n:link viewhelper. It expects an array of parameters as argument that are passed on to the typolink generation.

Important: 
Make sure that you wrap more complex values in single quotes or you will end up getting errors. See the quoted value of *additionalParams* in this example:

```
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" configuration="{addQueryString:1, additionalParams:'&tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]=3'}" title="{newsItem.title}"> 
... 
</n:link>
```